# How can we write a contract that relies on hidden information?

Tags: contract-design, privacy

Since a smart contract can only access (public) information on the blockchain itself, how can I make a smart contract that relies on hidden / secret information? Are there any workarounds in this situation?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In simple terms, you can't.

In more complex terms, depending on your specific application, there are [various forms of cryptography](https://blog.ethereum.org/2016/01/15/privacy-on-the-blockchain/) that you can use to achieve something similar to your desired objective, although most of the tooling around this crypto is still being developed.

Answer (score 3):

Workarounds: Use whisper for hidden communication channels instead. Then at least you can send encrypted communication to some other person. (But, it's not seen a lot of development love.)

I'm not sure if things can be sent to/from a contract, I'd default to thinking no.

Answer (score 2):

There are some research attempts [here](http://enigma.media.mit.edu/enigma_full.pdf) (Enigma) and [here](https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/675.pdf) (Hawk) at maintaining data confidentiality in smart contracts:

- In [Enigma](http://enigma.media.mit.edu/enigma_full.pdf) no single party ever has access to data in its
  entirety.
- In [Hawk](https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/675.pdf) the blockchain is used to enforce the process in a
  contract while limiting visibility of the state.

Neither of these are mature enough for public release (so won't really address your needs in the short short-term), and its also appears that both of the above result in some loss of generality.